# Functional Programming: Perimeter of a polygon.

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to find the perimeter of a polygon in a functional way. I tried my best but I couldn't make it purely functional. This is my code:

```
object Solution {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var x:Double = 0
    val N = scala.io.StdIn.readInt
    val points = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines().take(N).map(x=>x).toList
    for(i <- 0 to N-1){
      if(i==N-1) x+=dist(List(points(i),points(0)))
      else x += dist(List(points(i),points(i+1)))
    }
    println(x)
  }
  def dist(A: List[String]): Double = {
    scala.math.sqrt(scala.math.pow((A(0).split(" ")(0).toDouble-A(1).split(" ")(0).toDouble),2) + scala.math.pow((A(0).split(" ")(1).toDouble-A(1).split(" ")(1).toDouble),2))
  }
}
```

I enter the number of points of the polygon first and then enter Cartesian coordinates of each point in a new line.

Can anyone help me make it purely functional?

Comment: `.map(x=>x)` does not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with separating concerns:

```
// dist should just take 2 points
def dist(a: (Double,Double), b: (Double,Double)): Double = ...

// calculate perimeter
def perimeter (points: List[(Double,Double)]): Double = {
  // create a list of lines by connecting adjacent points
  val lines = points zip (points.tail ++ List(points.head))
  // aggregate the length of each line using foldLeft (/:)
  (0d /: lines)((acc, line) => acc ++ dist(line._1, line._2))
}

def main (args: Array[String]) {
  // main just needs to parse the lines
  val points = ... // parse the points

  println(perimeter(points))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I retained my dist function definition and made it a recursive one. That helped me make it functional.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `val n = 5` points

```
val points = (1 to n).map(_ => Math.random * 10).toArray
```

and a distance function, for example

```
def dist(a: Double, b: Double) = math.abs(a-b)
```

Then iterate *continually* (in circles) `n` times on (grouped) pairs of points to which we apply `dist`,

```
Iterator.continually(points)
        .flatten
        .sliding(2)
        .take(n)
        .map { case a :: b :: Nil => dist(a,b) }
        .sum
```